# FreeNAS ZFS questions about CPU, Ram, & HD speed

Tags: hard-drive, sata, nas, freenas, intel-atom

I'd like to build the most energy efficient NAS possible but still be able to run FreeNAS with ZFS.

- I've been looking at Atom processors, but haven't found any that
  could support more than 4gb of ram.  Is ATOM fastest enough to
  handle a 3-5 harddrive ~10TB NAS (mostly for drop storage movies, photos, etc.)?  I've read you should have ~1gb or ram per tb of disk (ZFS).  Is an Atom powered
  (4GB Ram) NAS unrealistic?
- Second question, for the harddrives what should be my minimum
  requirements?  IE Would 5400, 5900 vs 7200RPM or SATA
  3.0/6.0/gb/s make a tangible difference for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Freenas box running from a Celeron processor that is just slightly faster than the average desktop Atom.

Mine handles 4 hard drives just fine - remember that file operations are not CPU intensive, that is handled separately by the I/O controller.

The CPU will only be used if you choose to use Software Raid, and on my box, I stream movies all the time and the CPU barely goes above 20%, so, I am sure you will be fine.

As for hard drive speeds, this is a very hard one. 5400RPM drives will use up less electricity, but, it is possible for it to slow down write activities across the network (read/heavy copying as well, but, it should be fast enough for streaming and regular stuff). Only you can decide this. I personally went for 7200RPM drives on mine.

Comment: Yes, I will be using the software based RAID, but that sounds great.  I was thinking about 5900 as for many of the "Green" drives it seems to be a lucky number.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the maximum RAM: There are Boards with Atom-CPUs supporting 8 GB RAM: [Asrock AD525PV3](http://asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=AD525PV3&cat=Specifications)

I haven't found a pattern (NM10 chipset or ION), but occasionally some boards do...

Comment: Yes, but does FreeNAS amd64 run on an Atom? Because FreeNAS i386 will have a 4GB memory limit.

Answer (score 2):

> 1gb or ram per tb of disk

Ideally, ZFS requires about [2GB of memory for each TB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Deduplication) of storage *only* if deduplication is enabled, because of the relatively large deduplication table. 1GB of memory per TB is probably overkill otherwise, especially for typical home server use. Also, FreeNAS 8 only supports [v15](http://www.freenas.org/category/version-comparison) of ZFS, which [does not include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Version_numbers) deduplication support.

Faster RPM drives have [better random read/write speeds](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5042/seagates-new-barracuda-3tb-st3000dm001-review), at at the cost of higher power consumption. If performance is important to you, then that is your answer.